# Using sed to replace only inside a regexp substring

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I have a log where i want to apply a replace just inside a regexp match text.

Example, take this log line:

```
date machine  text random text and yet more random text - status code
```

i want o replace the all spaces by a _ inside the text area, without replacing all other spaces in the log. the output would be this:

```
date machine  text_random_text_and_yet_more_random_text - status code
```

To match the area i want to replace i have this regexp:

```
/machine \(.*\) - /
```

As the text is not standard, i can have one space to 20, so its hard to match it directly, so i match the start and the end of the substring.

Trying to use it i tried this:

```
sed `/machine \(.*\) - /   s/ /_/g '  logfile
```

but of course, it will replace all spaces in the log, not just the matched substring.

I managed to do it with awk, by iterating and printing each field until i find the `machine`, where i change the `OFS="_"` and restore it to space when i find the `-`. It works... yet, i was curious if this is possible to solve using sed.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what sed supports when it concerns the few 'advanced' regex syntax, but with PCRE, you can do it like [that](http://regex101.com/r/sW0uM7).

Comment: Sed don't have PCRE, but that is a interesting site! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\S+\s+){2}/&\n/;s/\s+-/\n&/;h;y/ /_/;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/' file
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and uses sed!! i had tried to inserting newlines to break the log, but in my attempt i required several sed commands and didn't feel right. Your solution is looks perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Since there are two space before text you like to have with underscore and space - space after, you can do like this:

```
awk -F "  | - " '/machine/ {gsub(/ /,"_",$2)}1' file
date machine text_random_text_and_yet_more_random_text status code
```

Comment: that `}1` is unknown for me... can you explain it, or point me to some doc? i don't know even how to search for that in google!! :) i can see it prints the line, but changing the number to other than 0 does the same thing.

Comment: `1` does mean print any line.  Its always true, so it will do the default action, print. It could be written like this `1 {print $0}`.  So this `awk`will change value of filed `$2`, when its `machine`, and then the `1` does print all lines, including the modified lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one gnu-awk command to solve this:

```
s='date machine text random text and yet more random text - status code'
awk '{gsub(/ /, "_", $2); print $1 " machine " $2 " - " $3}' FS='machine *| *- *' <<<"$s"

date machine  text_random_text_and_yet_more_random_text - status code
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk solution might be:

```
awk '{
    # Capture the stringpart in `a`rray
    match($0,"machine  (.*) -",a)
    # Make the changes
    gsub(" ","_",a[1])
    print gensub("machine (.*) -","machine  " a[1] " -","g")
}' INPUTFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
echo "date machine  text random text and yet more random text - status code" | 
perl -pe 's/(?<=machine  )(.*)(?= - )/ ($repl = $1) =~ s{\s}{_}g; $repl /e'
```

```
date machine  text_random_text_and_yet_more_random_text - status code
```